# Java io.tempdir returns null on ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

What I've tried:

`class TempDir {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tempdir"));
    }
}`

I need to keep a script consistent with Windows and Linux, windows returns temp directory however, ubuntu returns null, I'm not sure why?

Comment: It's just `null`, there is no error?

Comment: Is this the program you're actually running?  Because the property is "java.io.tmpdir" not "java.io.tempdir".

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

Prints /tmp on my Ubuntu system, so it looks like you mispelled the property name.

Comment: You might want to explain that you fixed the misspelling of `tempdir` to `tmpdir`.